# How to display total count of data on angular material table pagination from rest api which is fetching at the time 10 records

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display the total count of all records on the angular material pagination, I was to trying the access the 10 records from the rest api, by sending pageIndex and pageSize according to the pageSizeOptions selected, but count is displayed as 0 - 100 of 100 only even though there are more records, how to enable next page arrow, currently it is disabled.

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="entityList" class="table table-bordered" matSort matSortDirection="asc" matSortActive="createdAt" matSortDisableClear  *ngIf="resultsNotFound === false">
                            <thead></thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let colDet of otherColumns">
                               
                                <ng-container matColumnDef="{{colDet['name']}}">
                                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="{{colDet['name']}}">{{colDet['label']}}</th>
                                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]="formatDate(element[colDet.name],colDet.name)"></td>
                                </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="createdAt">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="createdAt">Created At</th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    {{ element.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YY hh:mm A' }}</td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="updatedAt">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="updatedAt">Updated At</th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    {{ element.updatedAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YY hh:mm A' }}</td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="statusCd">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="statusCd">Status</th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.statusCd }}</td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row let i = index">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="viewEntity(row)">View</button>
                                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="deleteMBC(row.id, i)">Comment</button> -->
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns()"></tr>
                            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns();"></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                
                        <mat-paginator *ngIf="entityList" [length]="totalLength" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 100, 200 ]"   [pageSize]="fetchRecords"  
                        (page)="loadMore($event)">
                        </mat-paginator>
                    </div>
```

.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.entityList.paginator = this.paginator;  
   
  }

ngOnInit() {
   
    this.pageNumber = 0;
    this.fetchRecords = 10;
    this.getDataModelList();
   
  }
getDataModelList()
{
this.entityService.getEntityList(this.pageNumber, this.fetchRecords)
      .subscribe(list => {
       
        this.totalLength = this.totalLength + list.length;
        this.entityList = new MatTableDataSource<any>(list);
        
        this.entityList.sort = this.sort;

});
}

 loadMore(e: any) {
    console.log(e);
    this.pageNumber = e.pageIndex
    
    /* this.pageNumber = e.pageSize * e.pageIndex */
    if(!this.newFlag)
    {
    this.entityService.getEntityList(e.pageIndex, e.pageSize)
      .subscribe(list => {
                         
                            this.entityList = new MatTableDataSource();
                            this.entityList.data = list;
                 
                          });
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

include

```
   @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

and find length from response and replace it with this.pagination.pageSize

```
        this.paginator.pageSize = this.pagination.pageSize;
```

i guess you need to acheive this ?

[image]

if that's the thing then

```
<mat-paginator (page)="changePage($event)" [length]="tableAttributes.totalRecords" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="pagination.pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pagination.pageSizeOptions"
            [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
        </mat-paginator>
```

you have to modify [length] and you are good to go

Comment: I am passing pagesize acorrding to pageSize option to api, my requirement is to get total records on pagination

Comment: i have edited my answer please check it if that's what you need

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a pagination on your backend, bringing only a slice of the collection, you'll need to create a component to paginate by yourself. Material Paginator, deals with the list that he receive. So if you get only 10 records, it will show:
 `1 - {{PAGESIZE}} of 10` everytime that you fetch the data.
Your 'Next Page' button is probably disable because it's has only 10 itens on the list.
If you want to get all records, you can use Material Pagination, and add the following tag on your html:
`<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>`

This way, the pagination will manage thr whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi i got only solution of this problem of this problem create a table by using model code**
**this.dynamicColumn column array of mat table
this.datasource.data is the data source of the table**
code here
https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/1890

```
enter code here
 exportToPdf() {
let str: string = '';
let table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute('id', 'testpdTable');
let heasRow = '';
this.dynamicColumns.forEach((value: any) => {
  heasRow = heasRow + `<th scope="col" >${value}</th>`;
});
heasRow = `<tr>${heasRow} <tr> `;
let tableData = this.datasource.data
  .map((value1, index) => {
    str = str + `<td >${index + 1}</td>`;
    this.dynamicColumns.map((value: any) => {
      if (value !== 'SrNo') {
        str = str + `<td >${value1[value]}</td>`;
      }
    });

    let str1 = `<tr>${str} <tr> `;
    str = '';
    return str1;
  })
  .join('');
const footer: any = document.querySelector('#footer');
console.log(footer.innerHTML);
let myfoot = document.createElement('tr');
myfoot.setAttribute('class', 'thead-dark');
myfoot.innerHTML = footer.innerHTML;
table.innerHTML =
  `<thead><tr>${heasRow} <tr></thead> ` +
  `<tbody>${tableData}</tbody>` +
  `<tfoot class="thead-dark bold-font bodytext-color ps-3" >${footer.innerHTML} </tfoot>`;
console.log();
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
doc.text('E-ceiling Report', 130, 10);
doc.setFontSize(11);
doc.setTextColor(100);
autoTable(doc, { html: table, showFoot: 'lastPage' });
//  doc.text("https://rajkosh..in",10, 200);
//  doc.save("Report.pdf");
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
}
```